# Cypress - Passing a function to .should() using Chrome

Tags: cypress

The Cypress.IO documentation allows a function to be passed to should: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should.html#Function

This works if I run my test headless or with electron but fails in Chrome as the argument passed to the function is null.

I know the element exists because I tested it previously.

cypress_runner.js:197677 AssertionError: Target cannot be null or undefined.

```
describe('Cypress ', () => {

    it(`Works `, () => { 
      cy.get('span').should('have.length',25);
      cy.get('span').should(($span) => {
        expect($span).to.have.length(25);
      });
    });
  })
```

Comment: What is your cypress version? It works for me for `4.8.0`.